# How to undeploy the Prediction IO model

Tags: predictionio

I am working with logistic regression using prediction io template. I have been deployed a model using `pio deploy`. It gives me a port where I am testing my problem. My question is how to undeploy the model. Is there any command to undeploy Or I have to find the PID of port using `netstat -npl | grep port no` and manually kill the PID.

Comment: I am in search for the same answer. The best that I have found is to kill the process.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `pio undeploy`

```
pio undeploy --ip <user_ip> --port <user_port>
```

Comment: Thanks, tried `pio undeploy` but getting the following response: 

`[INFO] [Engine$] Undeploying any existing engine instance at http://0.0.0.0:8000
[ERROR] [Engine$] Another process is using http://0.0.0.0:8000, or an existing engine server is not responding properly (HTTP 405). Unable to undeploy` 


My Engine is sitting idle, still getting the error.

Answer (score 2):

another way to undeploy your running engine server is to perform a `GET` on the `/stop` endpoint of the server.

Using a browser simply goto:

```
http://<host>:<port>/stop
```

Using curl it would look like

```
curl <host>:<port>/stop
```

Source:

https://github.com/PredictionIO/PredictionIO/blob/develop/core/src/main/scala/io/prediction/workflow/CreateServer.scala#L651

Comment: Tried on PIO 0.12 build, seems like they support only `POST` now: `HTTP method not allowed, supported methods: POST`