# Predicition.io - Undeploy prediction model

Tags: apache-spark, machine-learning, predictionio

I want to undeploy an already deployed predictionio model, but didn't find any help so far.

There is another post [How to undeploy the Prediction IO model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32886550/how-to-undeploy-the-prediction-io-model)
 from stack overflow but it's also not working for me.

I am using:

pio    0.12.0-incubating

scala  2.11.8

spark  2.1.0

Any idea how to undeploy in pio 0.12.0?

Comment: What do you mean it doesn't work for you ? Is there an error ?

Comment: I ran command pio undeploy --port 8122 and had this error: [ERROR] [Engine$] Another process is using http://0.0.0.0:8121, or an existing engine server is not responding properly (HTTP 405). Unable to undeploy. Same happens by giving ip address too.